UserWarning: SymbolDatabase.GetPrototype() is deprecated. Please use message_factory.GetMessageClass() instead
I have this code where I label fingers using MediaPipe and OpenCV:
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
from mediapipe import solutions

mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mp_hands.Hands(
    static_image_mode=False,
    max_num_hands=2,
    min_detection_confidence=0.5,
    min_tracking_confidence=0.5,
)
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

finger_indices = [
    mp_hands.HandLandmark.THUMB_TIP,
    mp_hands.HandLandmark.INDEX_FINGER_TIP,
    mp_hands.HandLandmark.MIDDLE_FINGER_TIP,
    mp_hands.HandLandmark.RING_FINGER_TIP,
    mp_hands.HandLandmark.PINKY_TIP,
]


def label_fingers(frame, fingers, hand_landmarks, frame_width, frame_height):
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    font_scale = 1.0
    color = (255, 0, 0)
    thickness = 2
    line_type = cv2.LINE_AA

    for idx, finger in enumerate(finger_indices):
        landmark = hand_landmarks.landmark[finger]
        x = int(landmark.x * frame_width)
        y = int(landmark.y * frame_height)
        text = str(fingers[idx])
        org = (x, y)
        cv2.putText(frame, text, org, font, font_scale, color, thickness, line_type)


async def process_video_stream(frame, fingers):
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (600, 400))
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    result = hands.process(rgb_frame)

    if result.multi_hand_landmarks:
        frame_height, frame_width = frame.shape[:2]
        for hand_landmarks in result.multi_hand_landmarks:
            mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
                frame,
                hand_landmarks,
                mp_hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS,
                solutions.drawing_styles.get_default_hand_landmarks_style(),
                solutions.drawing_styles.get_default_hand_connections_style(),
            )
            label_fingers(frame, fingers, hand_landmarks, frame_width, frame_height)

    return frame

The code works well, but I get the following warning message:
/home/khalid/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/protobuf/symbol_database.py:55: UserWarning: SymbolDatabase.GetPrototype() is deprecated. Please use message_factory.GetMessageClass() instead. SymbolDatabase.GetPrototype() will be removed soon.
  warnings.warn('SymbolDatabase.GetPrototype() is deprecated. Please '

I don't know where in the code the deprecated SymbolDatabase.GetPrototype() function is being called so I can replace it with the new message_factory.GetMessageClass() method. How can I locate and update this deprecated function usage?

The error is not in the code but rather the protobuf library that has been installed as a part of mediapipe installation. I faced this error as well quite recently with Face Landmark detection and the way to solve this is by managing the versions of mediapipe and protobuf. What worked for me was mediapipe version 0.10.11 and protobuf version 3.20.3
More information can be found on this github issue link: https://github.com/google-ai-edge/mediapipe/issues/5361
